# Spring WebClient: What is the default multiplier for Retry.backoff?

Tags: spring, spring-webclient, reactor-netty

I am trying to understand the the default multiplier for exponential backoff strategy for Spring WebClient Retry.backoff method. And can this be configured? I cannot find documentation for this.

https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/util/retry/Retry.html#backoff-long-java.time.Duration-

**Version:**
reactor-netty 0.9.12.RELEASE

Comment: this may help: [baeldung spring-retry](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-retry)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The utility method `Retry.backoff`, as you said correctly, creates an exponential backoff strategy.  The multiplier is 2. In other words, the backoff period doubles in length on each retry/failure.

You can see this in action in [reactor.util.retry.RetryBackoffSpec#generateCompanion](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/677e8c0d3ee08209feb225ef412645d87c3c9ad5/reactor-core/src/main/java/reactor/util/retry/RetryBackoffSpec.java#L562).

The "multiplier", as you can see, is hardcoded and is therefore not configurable out-the-box. In order to use something other than `2` you would create your own `Retry` implementation and specifically implement the `generateCompanion()` method to do logic as is done in `RetryBackoffSpec` but using your own custom multiplier.

Comment: Accepting this as answer as I have manually verified by implementing it so that nobody has to verify it again.